# Removing a glowing Artifact from a series of 200-300 photos (Animation)

Tags: animation, automation, visual-artifacts

So I've created a series of photos with Blender tying together into an animation but there's a glowing ring artifact in approximately 200 images that I would like to get rid of. Is there any way to automate this process with any program?

Here's a picture of the artifact I want to get rid of:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to remove this ring in Blender before rendering?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's a [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) where this question might be better suited.  If you want you can flag your own question and ask ask the mods to move there for you.

Comment: The problem is I can't get it out in Blender because it is a light Gizmo which can't be hidden without removing it's emission, so I thought maybe I can remove it post render?

Comment: In the 3D tool I know best (modo) I can determine whether an emission object is visible to camera or not - I think in Blender you can too - Object Properties>Ray Visibility check camera off I think. Probably a lot faster and easier to re-render correctly than remove in post.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working in the Eevee engine due to time constraints, the feature hasn't been implemented yet as far as I know, I tried finding it all morning :/ I'll live with it for now and hope it doesn't bother too much in the final product :)

Answer (score 2):

This could be just a comment but here I go.

Well, just to recap. Yes, try to remove the object in the object properties inside Blender. You could ask in https://blender.stackexchange.com/

But if you want to do it in another program, you could use one that has object tracking like Davinci Resolve. Look for a specific tutorial googling this: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=davinci+resolve+removing+objects.

The problem is that you have a texture that will probably make a different artifact on the rendered final video, it probably will look like a ghost, which you ould patch making a second pass in Blender without the object, which leads us to step 1, making some kind of additional pass inside Blender.